# "Load more" pagination button in multiple tables. Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form that queries a database and returns information placed in multiple tables.  The row count of each column can reach into the hundreds.  Each row is returned as a custom model I declared.  All the rows for a certain table are stored in an object container.

I want to initially only load the first 50 rows in each table.  At the bottom of each table I want to place a "Load More" button which, on click, loads 50 more queries (or the rest of the result if it is less than 50).

Django's pagination tutorial makes it seem like I can only do pagination split up into different pages.  Can I make row pagination with a load more button?  Or is what I want impossible to create?

EDIT: Here is how I'm currently printing the rows for each table, it's a simple for loop

> ```
> {% for r in row %} 
> <tr>
> <td>{{ r.name }}</td>
> <td>{{ r.age }}</td>
> <td>{{ r.state }}</td> </tr>
> ```
>
> {% endfor %}

This is my view for 1 table:

```
pers = Personal.objects.all()
pers = formfilter (name, age, state)

c = RequestContext(request, {
    "cname": name})

return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Comment: where are your views codes for that table. We can create selected options for that. In that options, we can define 50, 70, or 80, depends on what you like. User can select how many queries he wants to show in a page. Are you using Paginator?

Comment: I edited in my view code

Comment: Try to use Paginator to resolve your problem

Comment: I'm going through the tutorials now, but there are only explanations for having multiple html pages.

Comment: Django has a built-in pagination,

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. You have to make an AJAX call to the server with the required information. When you handle this request in Django you should response with table rows only, means not the whole HTML page. Then on client when you receive this response just add it to the end of the table.

Response should looks like this:

```
<tr><td>col1 row 51</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>col1 row 100</td></tr>
```

Here is an expample JS code that may do the trick:

```
$.get("/yourapp/data", { page: 2}) .done(function(data) {
    $('.mytable').append(data);
});
```

But instead of just `{page: 2}` provide required for Django pagination information, I don't remember what they are. I believe `page` is all you need. Also you'd want to pass something to indicate that you are requesting only table rows, without the rest of the page.

Comment: What is the "/yourapp/data" link?  Is it the hyperlink for the second page of a specific table?

Comment: This is the page that will respond with the table content. Normally it is the same page where you see the table, but in this case you should pass something `rows_only:1` along with `page:2` and in your View retrieve this parameter and depending on its value render different templates. One template for the whole page and the second one for table rows only.